# Depurador Just-In-Time - Dev C++

Tags: dev-c++

Crio um código básico no Dev C++ e no momento que tento compilar e executar é apresentado a mensagem abaixo.

Sistema operacional: Windows 8 pro 
Versão Dev C++: 4.9.9.2

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Comment: O Dev-C++ é uma bomba então a melhor sugestão que posso dar é trocar de IDE.

Answer (score 1):

Após realizar download da versão 5.3.0.4 o problema não retornou.